# In Android Navigation Architecture, how can I get the previous fragment name?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

This is my fragment:

```
class InvoicesSettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var _navigationHost: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoices_settings, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _navigationHost = requireView().findNavController()
    }
    
}
```

I'd like to write the previous fragment name in the current fragment. **How can I get the previous fragment name?** I tried every property definied in `NavController` (`_navigationHost`) with no luck. The only other possibility I have in mind is to pass its name as an argument while navigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean by **fragment name**?

If you want the label of the fragmnet in `nav_graph`, you can get the `backStack` property of `NavController`

```
val backStack = findNavController().backStack.toList()
if (bacStack.size > 1) {
   val prevDest = backStack[backStack.size - 2]
   prevDest.destination.label // the label of the previous fragment
}
```

Comment: I believe the backStack property doesn't exist anymore in the NavController. You can use findNavController().backQueue instead.